# Passing value from multiline textbox using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asmx

I would like to pass the content from a multiline textbox into an sql database using jQuery .ajax.

```
function UpdateMemogramContent() {    
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MemogramWebServices.asmx/UpdateMemogramContent",
        data: "{ 'mId': " + $("#LabelId").text() + ", 'content': " + $("#TextBoxContent").text() + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: Success,
        error: Error
    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the content from the multiline textbox is throwing an invalid json primitive exception.  Taking a look at the POST:

> { 'mId': 314, 'content': Test
>
> Test}

What can I do to pass the text from a multiline textbox into an sql database using .ajax?

Comment: Have you tried $("#TextBoxContent").val() ?

Comment: tried using trim() before passing ?

Comment: Just like @Mayank said, you should use val() instead of text()

Comment: I got the content fine using .text().  I changed to .val() and the same problem.  Should I be wrapping the content in ''?

Comment: I suggest you remove the single quote from 'mId' and 'content'. Just use mId and content.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint before call posting data and look what value is you sending to server.
Also

1. change

> $("#TextBoxContent").text()

to

> $("#TextBoxContent").val()

1. if p.1 did not help; try replace

> data: "{ 'mId':

to

data: "{ mId: "

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an actual JavaScript structure like so. This will however pass mId and content as standard post parameters rather than one piece of JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MemogramWebServices.asmx/UpdateMemogramContent",
    data: { 
        mId:     $("#LabelId").text(), 
        content: $("#TextBoxContent").text()
    },
    ...
});
```

Otherwise, you can also use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) like so:

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify({ 
    mId:     $("#LabelId").text(), 
    content: $("#TextBoxContent").text()
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MemogramWebServices.asmx/UpdateMemogramContent",
    data: json_data,
    ...
});
```

Comment: I have no doubt this would work.  I ended up solving the problem using 'content': '" + $("#TextBoxContent").val() + "' }".  When passing a int, you can leave it along but you have to pass text as 'text'.  Thanks all!